# Can't open certain websites through SSL

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-connection, ssl

I recently switched to Window 8.1, I have problem in opening certain websites,
for example I can't open any Wikipedia page (through Google search or directly), browser fell into an infinite loading (nothing is shown, connecting... state)

- I have this problem both on Internet explorer and Firefox
- I am connected using ADSL modem but I hadn't this problem on my previous system, however I reconfigure it
- I set my DNS to Open DNS servers but I still have the problem

Interestingly if I enter the address without `https` and using just `http`, the browser opens the page!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by decreasing the MTU of my ADSL connection through the modem config

The detail of finding an optimal MTU can be found in this [article](http://blog.wisefaq.com/2009/09/01/determining-your-mtu-and-why-you-should-care/)

I set the MTU of PPoE connection to 1460, and now the pages are opened.